# Convert a Text File into an Array, without the '/n'

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am trying to code a sorting code, very basic, using the python "(sorted)" method. For this code, I am trying to import the words to be sorted by using a text file. I would like to import the data from the text file (.txt) to be clear. This is not the problem, its the output. Here is the code, and the output.

```py
text_file = open("WordsToSort-For-AlphabeticalSortProgram.txt", "r")
ListToSort = text_file.readlines()
text_file.close()

print(sorted(ListToSort, key=str.lower))
```

For more clarity, here is the data in the .txt file

```
Banana
Apple
Canada
```

Here is the output:

```
['Apple\n', 'Banana\n', 'Canada\n']
```

How do I make it so that it does not output the "\n" at the end of each word in the output?

EDIT: Formatting

Comment: `ListToSort = text_file.read().splitlines()`

Comment: `ListToSort = list(map(str.rstrip, text_file.readlines()))`

Comment: `strip()` will remove the linefeeds from your string - but I agree with @Barmar that you should just eliminate on the read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open(txt, 'r') as fp:
  lines = fp.readlines() 
for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    ListToSort.append(lines[i].rstrip('\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in open('your file name', 'r').readlines()]
```

Comment: This doesn't close the file after reading from it. Instead I suggest `with open('filename', 'r') as f: lines = sorted(lines.rstrip('\n') for line in f, key=str.lower)`. This will automatically close the file.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by @Barmar in the comments, the following code is working, with the output I am looking for.

```py
text_file = open("WordsToSort-For-AlphabeticalSortProgram.txt", "r")
ListToSort = text_file.read().splitlines()
text_file.close()

# save for testing: ListToSort = ["a", "C", "b"]

print(sorted(ListToSort, key=str.lower))
```

Comment: Sincer people might read and be inspired by this answer, I think it's better to show how to open a file in a `with` block than using `= open(...)` followed by `close()`.